# how to write this program for C++

Tags: c++

I need help with this question: A piece of wire is to be bent in the form of a rectangle to put around a picture frame. The length of the picture frame is 1.5 times the width. Write a program that prompts the user to input the length of the wire and the outputs the length and the width of the picture frame. I'm not sure if I should code something that has got to do with the perimeter.

I've tried to start it

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    double length;
    double width;

    cout << "Input the length of the wire:";
    cin >> length;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to add that I'm sorry that I didn't format the question right. For some reason my <iostream> didn't come off... I know that it's not showing on here but I have that up.

Comment: This isn't a _question_ so much as a "Write this entire program for me". I suggest you make a legitimate attempt, and if you are struggling with something you should ask then.

Comment: Wire length will be the perimeter of the rectangle, which is 2*(rectangle length + width) = 2*(1.5 width + width) = 5*width. So width is wire length / 5... Where is the problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Well you know that the length of the wire. So let's call that `L`.

Width will be `fW` and length of frame will be `fL`.

Then you have:

> 2*fW + 2*fL = L.
>
> fL = 1.5*fW
>
> 2*fW + 2*(1.5*fW) = L
>
> L = 5*fW
>
> fW = L/5.

So basically you know that the width of the frame will be length of wire divided by 5. And length will be 1.5 times that.

Comment: I did but since I have a bad reputation it won't show publicly; it will be recorded on the website, though. Sorry :/